# Removing trailing whitespaces from multiline output

Tags: powershell

For simplicity, let's have the following code:

```
$output = ((Get-Content -Encoding utf8 -Raw "$path\\$script" | Invoke-Expression) *>&1)
```

And let's say the output is:

```
Folder PATH listing for volume System
Volume serial number is 1234-5678
​
C:\TEMP
|   file1.txt
|   file2.txt
|
\---folderA
​
​
```

...with empty line(s) at the end.

My desire is to expand the code with additional pipeline to remove trailing whitespace from the multi-line output, not inside, but just at then end, i.e. line #3 should stay, even it is blank.

```
$output = ((Get-Content -Encoding utf8 -Raw "$path\\$script" | Invoke-Expression) *>&1) | ???
```

What `???` should be to get clean output?

Comment: If ```$output``` is currently a single value then ```string.Trim()``` should do the trick - if you want it in pipeline form try ```| foreach-object { $_.Trim() }```. If it's an array of values try ```| where-object { -not [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($_) }``` or simply ```| where-object { $_ }```

Comment: @mclayton - I am not trying to remove blank lines inside multiline text, but just at the end

Comment: Ωmega - ah, ok. Yeah, your update makes that clearer :-).

Comment: @mclayton - I apologize for not being clear at the first place. My bad.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon – trailing white-spaces are the result of `Invoke-Expression`, so script-code trimming is irrelevant.

Comment: Just to clarify, does ```$output``` currently contain a single multi-line string, or an array of single-line strings?

Comment: @mclayton - I am looking for both scenarios solution

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way to do it as a self-contained pipeline step - it's not pretty and I don't know what performance will be like for large datasets but it works...

```
$output = ... current pipeline ... `
    | foreach-object `
        -begin {
            $cache = new-object System.Collections.ArrayList;
        } `
        -process {
            $null = $cache.Add($_);
            if( -not [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($_) ) {
                $cache;
                $cache.Clear();
            }
        }
```

It basically keeps a cache of values until it meets a non-blank value and then flushes the cache into the output pipeline. When it eventually meets the trailing blank lines it keeps adding them to the cache but it doesn't flush them when it reaches the end of the input.

---

#### Update

The above assumes you want to *filter* and *return* the items in the input array - e.g.

```
$source = @(
    "Folder PATH listing for volume System",
    "Volume serial number is 1234-5678",
    "​",
    "C:\TEMP",
    "|   file1.txt",
    "|   file2.txt",
    "|",
    "\---folderA",
    "​",
    "​"
);
```

becomes

```
$result = @(
    "Folder PATH listing for volume System",
    "Volume serial number is 1234-5678",
    "​",
    "C:\TEMP",
    "|   file1.txt",
    "|   file2.txt",
    "|",
    "\---folderA"
);
```

*but* if you want to join the lines into a single string at the same time there's a couple of easier options:

**PS 7.2+**

```
$output = ... current pipeline... `
    | join-string -separator ([Environment]::NewLine) `
    | foreach-object { $_.TrimEnd() }
```

where the individual lines are first joined with line breaks as separators, and the trailing line breaks are then removed from the resulting multi-line string by `TrimEnd` (note that “embedded” blank lines are preserved).

PS 5.1 doesn't have the `Join-String` cmdlet but you can do this instead...

**PS 5.1**

```
$output = (
         (...current pipeline...) -join ([Environment]::NewLine)
    ).TrimEnd()
```

The output from both of these is equivalent to:

```
$result = @"
Folder PATH listing for volume System
Volume serial number is 1234-5678

C:\TEMP
|   file1.txt
|   file2.txt
|
\---folderA
"@;
```

Comment: Isn't there some simpler way to convert the output string array into a single multiline string and use `-replace '\s+\z', ''` to trim the white-space tail?

Comment: I’ve reworked the answer to give an option that uses ```join-string``` (PS7.2+) and a PS5.1 equivalent - hopefully something in there now will be suitable…

Comment: It certainly helped, but the result is not what I want - I am experiencing double `\n` for some reason

Comment: Strange. That kind of implies your current pipeline output is different to my ```$source``` test data - are you able to compare it to your existing ```$output``` for, e.g. trailing ```\n``` on your individual lines, or similar non-printing differences?

Comment: I believe `Invoke-Expression` is behind this very strange behavior.  See my answer - make a file with the test content and run my code in PS console (with correct path and filenames) to see if it works in your environment. Then check it with your code and let me know how it compares

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with this solution:

```
(((Get-Content -Encoding utf8 -Raw "$path\\$file1" | 
  Invoke-Expression) *>&1) | 
  % { $_ -replace '[^\S\n]+$', '' -replace '(?<=.)$', "`n" }) `
  -join '' -replace '(?ms)\s+(?!.)', '' | 
  Add-Content -NoNewline -Path "$path\\$file2"
```

---

Tested with this content of `$file1`:

```
(Get-WmiObject Win32_VideoController).CurrentHorizontalResolution
(Get-WmiObject Win32_VideoController).CurrentVerticalResolution
"`n`n`n`n`n`n`n"
Get-Process | Where { $_.MainWindowTitle -ne "" } | 
  Select ProcessName,MainWindowTitle |
  Sort-Object ProcessName |
  % { $_ -replace '(^\@\{ProcessName=|\}$)', '' } |
  % { ([regex]'^(.*?);.MainWindowTitle=').Replace($_, `
  { param($match) $match.Groups[1].Value.PadRight(50) }) } |
  Get-Unique
"`n`n`n`n`n`n`n"
tree 'C:\Temp' /F /A
"`n`n`n`n`n`n`n"
```

...and it works perfectly.